# Connecting to wifi network with captive portal login page using wpa_supplicant

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I am currently trying to connect to a BTWi-fi / BT_Openzone unsecured network in my office using my pcengines apu1d4 running debian 8.4 with edimax ew-7811un wifi dongle. 
When conventionally connecting to BTWi-fi through computer with web browser you are greeted with the BT captive portal (logon Page) where you enter your BT credentials however its not that simple when you are restricted to command line.

I need a way to automatically connect to this network and enter my bt credentials through the command line preferably using `wpa_supplicant`.

I'm guessing a template in `wpa_supplicant.conf` would look something like this :

```
network={
ssid="BTWi-fi"
key_mgmt=NONE

identity="MYBTUSERNAME@ME.CO.UK"
password="MYBTPASSWORD"
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We also have a similar situation here with the FON network in Nós (old ZON) operator. In the past I tried this procedure, nowadays they have randomised the initial URL to try to prevent this, I am planning do some tests in a near future.

BT and here our provider use captive portals to authenticate users. If I am not wrong, my own credentials work in BT in the UK (never tried).

The protocol used is the [WSIPr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr) protocol.

There are instructions for Linux, however they are rather old, and might need some work adapting to the current situation.

[WISPr Wireless ISP Autologin](http://wiki.maemo.org/WISPr_Wireless_ISP_Autologin)

The github/code whereupon these instructions are based is:

https://github.com/matsuu/auwifispot-client/blob/master/wispr_login.pl